# AWS RDS Failover - IIS Web Application

Tags: mysql, asp.net, iis, amazon-web-services

We are using Amazon RDS Multi-AZ mysql database and our web application uses IIS 8.5 and uses .net. Whenever there is a a failover with the mysql database, we have to manually "restart" the connection, so it refreshes to the new IP address of the mysql server. I'm sure it may eventually restart on it's own. Does anyone know the best approach to this issue? Was thinking about using "ConnectionLifeTime=...", but not sure what affect it would have on performance; or if the site was in the middle of a long query that happened to go over the time frame set in connectionlifetime, if it would drop/reset the connection in the middle of the query or if it would wait for the query to finish?